# How do I make my site publicly viewable? Everything redirects to wp-admin

Tags: login

When you do to the website, instead of displaying the pages as normal, it requires the WordPress user to login before viewing the site. No matter what URL I plug in for the site, it always redirects to /wp-login.php.

There aren't any plugins installed to prompt this kind of behavior, and nothing in the .htaccess file would either.

Any help in resolving this issue would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The pages are published and not set to private?

Comment: Deactivate your plugins and switch to a generic theme. Does it still do it?

Comment: Yeah, the pages are published, and not private. I was quite baffled, because the plugin set is the same as several other sites I'm working with, and this was the only one that was having issues. However, after deactivating the plugins, I noticed that one of them, which requires a license key for updates, hadn't been registered with the key yet, and was horribly out of date. Fixing that fixed the site. Thank you for you help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pages are published, and not private. I was quite baffled, because the plugin set is the same as several other sites I'm working with, and this was the only one that was having issues. However, after deactivating the plugins, I noticed that one of them, which requires a license key for updates, hadn't been registered with the key yet, and was horribly out of date. Fixing that fixed the site.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve your own question. Be sure to click the checkmark next to your answer to indicate that this question has been resolved. You can do that in the next two days.

Comment: Thanks, Ethan. Yeah, I tried right away, but it told me I'd have to wait for two days before accepting my own answer. I'll do what I can to stay on top of that.

Comment: To remind myself, I usually click the star next to my question which will be listed in my favorites for anything I need to look back into.